# Does stripping electrons from atoms or adding them affect the state of matter in any way?

Tags: charge, phase-transition, matter

Does electric charge affect melting, boiling point or sublimation temperature?

Comment: An extreme case of such an effect is [Coulomb explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_explosion).

Comment: Perhaps you could make it clear whether the material remains overall neutral or whether you are considering adding or taking away charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If electrons were stripped/added to every atom in the bulk of a substance in some condensed state, the no more neutral atoms would repel each other and the constituents would fly away.

**two cents...**
So lets make some atoms charged.
Depending on the solid, the effect of these charge centers might be different. For metals, the extra electron could get delocalised contributing to higher conductivity or conversely the positive ion could trap an electron. For ionic solids, it could act as an F center. For semiconductors, the excess/less charge could act as a dopant. Overtime, the excess electrons sprinkled in the bulk of the solid, would  tend to slowly diffuse to the surface and be lost to the environment or be trapped in surface states. Conversely, for positively charged ions, electrons would overtime leech into the substance from the environment.

What would be the effect of all this on melting/boiling(m/b) point? Note that at low concentrations, the thermal mass of the substance would mostly be the same as when it was uncharged. Also, there would be minimal lattice distortion. So negligible effect on m/b point would be expected. Nevertheless, since compared to the lowest energy config-the uncharged state-the substance is less stable, it would disintegrate faster given thermal energy so m/b pts. would slightly decrease.

For amorphous solids, the effect should be more pronounced as the charges would be truly stuck. Alas these have wide m/b pts. anyways.

For liquids,  the ions would form a surface layer elevating boiling points.